# Is $\{z: (z = u \cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$ a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

$u \cup v$ is the set defined by the axiom of union for the set $\{u,v\}$.

My intuition tells me that $\{z: (z = u \cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$ is indeed a set, because it is made by all of the elements contained on each $u \in U$ and on each $v \in V$, however I struggle to give a formal argument.

Right now the only tools at my disposal are the extensionality, comprehension, pairing, union, empty set, power set and regularity ZFC axioms.

I believe that in order to prove that $\{z: (z \in u \cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$ is a set using the axiom of union is the way to go, but  still find myself stuck.

Edit: Made a mistake while writing the set, wrote "$\{z: (z \in u \cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$" instead of "$\{z: (z = u \cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$" by mistake.

Comment: You haven't said what $U,V$ are, but this will be a set, if $U,V$ are sets.

Comment: When you say "prove that it is a set," do you mean to prove "$\forall U\forall V\exists Z\forall z[z\in Z\iff(\exists u\in U)(\exists v\in V)(z\in u\lor z\in v)]$" or something else?

Comment: @R.Burton what I mean by "prove that it is a set" is to show that a such a set can be built by using the ZFC axioms I cited, starting with any U and V sets.

Comment: The real problem is, you don't say what the conditions are on $u,v.$ Is it supposed to be for all $u,v$ in $U,V,$ respectively, of only some? That is, is it $\forall u,v$ or $\exists u,v.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understood it to be $G(U,V)$ as you wrote it. But the OP doesn't list replacement among the permitted axioms, and I'm not sure how to go about this without using replacement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I got the wrong name. Anyway, I don't think the question is about whether or not the result is a set - that's obvious - it's how to prove it using only the axioms listed. The OP edited the question, so the set isn't $\bigcup(U\cup V)$

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a way to prove what I intended via the ZFC axioms I'm allowed to use:

Using the axiom of union $\cup U$ and $\cup V$ are both sets (because $U$ and $V$ are sets by hypothesis)

By the pairing axiom, $\{ \cup U, \cup V\}$ is a set too.

Using the axiom of union again, I get that $\cup \{ \cup U, \cup V\}$ is also a set.

Finally, using the power set axiom, $P (\cup \{ \cup U, \cup V\})$

Then, using comprehension, $A=\{z \in P (\cup \{ \cup U, \cup V\})\} : (z=u\cup v) \wedge (u \in U) \wedge (v \in V) \}$ is also a set.

$A$ seems to be the set that the exercise asks for (after all, what I needed were subsets of $\cup \{\cup U, \cup V\}$)

The only step where I'm not completely sure of the reasoning is the last one where I use comprehension. Because comprehension asks for both a set and a property that the elements of the set should fulfill... But I feel like my property might be tricky.